# как избежать повторения css правил в Bootstrap 3.3.6 для XS SM

Tags: bootstrap, media-queries

```
nav ul li {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/2x2') repeat;
}

/* Portrait phones and smaller XS */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    nav ul li{ background: none}
}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets  XS*/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    nav ul li{ background: none}
}

/* SM */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    nav ul li{ background: none}
}

/* MD */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

}

/* LG */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## UPD. Как медиа-запросы разрешают поесть мороженого

Представим, что отец объясняет сыну, когда можно полакомиться мороженым. Тогда медиа-запросы будут звучать так:

```
/* можешь есть мороженое */
nav ul li {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/2x2') repeat;
}

/* но в понедельник - нельзя */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    nav ul li{ background: none}
}

/* и во вторник - тоже нельзя */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    nav ul li{ background: none}
}

/* в среду и четверг - разумеется, нельзя */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    nav ul li{ background: none}
}

/* а в пятницу делай, как я сказал */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
}

/* и на выходных делай, как я сказал */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}
```

### Медиа-запросы нужны, когда что-то меняется

Ваш код описывает одно-единственное изменение:

> Начиная с 992px добавить к ссылкам фоновое изображение.

Но берёт для этого несоразмерно мелкие интервалы и к каждой проверке снизу `(min-width: ...)` добавляет проверку сверху `and (max-width: ...)`. Получается чересчур много инструкций. Код будет тяжело читать и сопровождать.

Бутстрап работает в логике `mobile first`. Сначала определяем стили для самых узких экранов. Потом переопределяем их, когда экран достигает нужной нам ширины. Получается так:

```
/* вообще-то тебе мороженого нельзя */
nav ul li { background: none }

/* но начиная с пятницы - ладно, угощайся */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  nav ul li {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/2x2') repeat;
  }
}
```

Этот код эквивалентен вашему. Его медиа-запрос действует и для `MD`, и для `LG`, потому что проверяет только нижнюю границу интервала.

### Учтём значение по умолчанию

Если в предшествующих стилях фон для ссылок не задавался, то строка `nav ul li { background: none }` тоже не нужна. Достаточно так:

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  nav ul li {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/2x2/cfc/&text=%20') repeat;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Фон ссылок станет зелёным</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">при ширине экрана от 992px</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: То есть если фон нужен для MD и LG То писать его в @media для MD и LG , в смысле повторить для два раза стили ? потому что написав в MD media для LG он не унаследуется

Comment: @МансурШайхаев Код в моём ответе **полностью** эквивалентен вашему. Он действует и для MD, и для LG, потому что мой медиа-запрос проверяет только нижнюю границу интервала. Вы к `@media (min-width: ...)` добавили   `and (max-width: ...)` и этим создали себе лишние трудности.

Comment: @МансурШайхаев  Добавил в ответ аналогию с мороженым, чтобы пояснить, как сокращать количество медиа-запросов. Чем ещё помочь?